# Project Euler #4 in C++: largest palindrome product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, palindrome

[Project Euler #4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4)

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers.

Any reviews are accepted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
bool isPalindrome(std::string num);
int findLargestProduct();
int main(){
        std::cout << findLargestProduct() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}

bool isPalindrome(std::string  num){
        std::string oldnum = num;
        reverse(oldnum.begin(),oldnum.end());
        if(oldnum == num)
                return true;
        else
                return false;

}

int findLargestProduct(){
        int largest,prod =0;
        for(int i =100;i<=999;i++){
                for(int j =100; j<=999;j++){
                        prod = i*j;
                        if(isPalindrome(std::to_string(prod)) && prod > largest){
                                largest = prod;
                        }
                }

        }
        return largest;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Answer (score 10):

#### Excessive spacing and `main()`

To start with, 4-space tabs please. 8 is tooooo much, you're using up all the horizontal space!

Additionally, `return 0;` from `main()` is optional. If you omit it, the compiler will provide it for you - so you don't have to write it.

#### `isPalindrome()`

This function doesn't modify its input - you take a copy, reverse it, and then compare the two. But actually you're making *two* copies of the input - one into `num` and the other into `oldnum`. If you took the argument by reference-to-const, you save yourself a copy for free:

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string const& num) { .. }
```

Additionally, the argument should probably be named `oldnum` - since that's the one that doesn't change.

Avoid code that looks like: `if (expr) return true; else return false;` That's an extremely verbose way of writing `return expr;` Altogether, this becomes:

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string const& oldnum) {
    std::string revnum = oldnum;
    std::reverse(revnum.begin(), revnum.end());
    return oldnum == revnum;
}
```

However, this is pretty inefficient - we have to make another copy of `oldnum` just to check if it's reversible? We can do that directly in one go. Just compare the `i`th element to the `N-i`th element and make sure they all line up:

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string const& num) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num.size()/2; ++i) {
        if (num[i] != num[num.size()-i-1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // still here? must be a palindrome
    return true;
}
```

This saves you a copy, so will be quite a bit faster.

#### `findLargestProduct()`

There is undefined behavior here. When you write:

```
int largest, prod = 0;
```

That isn't initializing `largest`, only `prod`. Which is unfortunate since it's only `largest` that needs to be initialized. Avoid this kind of multiple initialization, and simply do:

```
int largest = 0;
```

`prod` you can simply declare inside the inner-most loop.

Now, the slowest part of this function is `isPalindrome()`. That's an expensive operation to do - so we want to do it as rarely as possible! As an optimization, we can check if `prod > largest` *first* - so you avoid the expensive logic in all the cases where the outcome doesn't matter. If the product isn't the new max, who cares, right? That is:

```
int prod = i*j;
if (prod > largest && isPalindrome(std::to_string(prod))) {
    largest = prod;
}
```

Once we're there, let's really make sure we never have to do it by iterating in the opposite order:

```
for (int i=999; i>=100; --i) {
    for (int j=999; j>=100; --j) {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Math is cool

Assuming the answer will be 6 digits (seems safe), we know it's divisible by 11. We know this because the digits of the number will be \$abccba\$, and the handy rule for checking divisibility by 11 is to sum the even digits and the odd digits and check if the difference is divisible by 11 - and both the even digits (\$b+c+a\$) and the odd digits (\$a+c+b\$) have the same sum. Since we know it's divisible by 11, we know one of the factors must be divisible by 11. Let's pick `j`. This let's us reduce the loop to:

```
for (int i=999; i>=100; --i) {
    for (int j=990; j>=100; j-=11) { // largest 3-digit multiple of 11
       ...
    }
}
```

#### Breakdown of timing

Here's a breakdown of all the things I just suggested:

```
as-is                  171.5ms
better isPalindrome    138.0ms
flip ordering            9.9ms
iterate backwards        4.8ms
count by 11s             0.2ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing isPalindrome to accept an int parameter.  That you determine if a number is a palindrome by formatting as a string is an implementation detail that callers don't need to know about.  That leaves you the flexibility to change the implementation if you want.  Extracting digits with things like `(num / 10) % 10` may not be faster by itself, but you will avoid the string allocation.

Comment: In my experience, extracting digits like this is generally much faster than playing around with strings. If you need speed, avoid strings and manipulate integers directly.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         for(int i =100;i<=999;i++){
>                 for(int j =100; j<=999;j++){
>                         prod = i*j;
>                         if(isPalindrome(std::to_string(prod)) && prod > largest){
> ```

As [@Barry noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115483/71574), you can save time by doing this in the opposite order.  Another optimization is to stop looking once `largest > prod`.  With this code, you could write that

```
        for (int i = 999; i >= 100; --i){
                for (int j = 990; j >= 100; j -= 11) {
                        int product = i*j;

                        if (largest >= product) {
                                break;
                        }

                        if (isPalindrome(std::to_string(product))) {
```

Now it stops iterating through the inner loop once `product` is smaller than `largest`.  This shaved off 10-20% of the time in my tests.

I changed from `prod` to `product` for readability reasons.

You can also break inside the `isPalindrome` `if`.  For a given `i`, we'll never find a larger `product`, as the rest of the `j` values are smaller than the current one.